# Can organ-accumulated iron get shed again?

Tags: pathology

Hemochromatosis can lead to an accumulation of iron in some organs. If the accumulated amount is not too high, will it go down again upon correction of blood iron levels?

Comment: What research, if any, did you do to answer your own question? I believe this is very easy to answer with a quick search.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I did quite a bit of googling, and reading articles. I might not be using the right keywords.

Comment: Please cite an article on the treatment of  hemochromatosis which you read that didn't answer the question. Then I'd be happy to share what I know.

Comment: @anongoodnurse https://hemochromatosishelp.com/iron-overload/

Comment: I'm sorry to be so picky, but that is not a reputable source; it's a for profit blogsite that sells supplements. The Mayo clinic is reliable and easy to understand.

Comment: @anongoodnurse sure, there you go: https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/hemochromatosis/symptoms-causes/syc-20351443 (it still doesn't answer my question)

Comment: Did you read the second page? The answer is there.

Comment: @anongoodnurse It doesn't. Nowhere does it say specifically whether iron accumulated in organs gets eliminated. It only talks about outcomes (e.g. "Phlebotomy will not reverse cirrhosis", which of course it won't since cirrhosis is about tissue scarring). And to me, "reduce your iron levels to normal", sounds like blood levels, although it's unclear. Maybe some organs shed the excess iron much more slowly, just like they would with e.g. lead. This is my last reply to you, as your comments are starting to border on trolling. If you don't want to or can't answer, that's fine.